# Basis unit vectors in Orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinates, how to calculate?

Tags: vector-spaces, polar-coordinates, orthogonality, curvilinear-coordinates

Bipolar cylindrical coordinates (u, v, w) are defined by the transformation equations

x =a sinh v/(cosh v − cos u), y =a sin u/(cosh v − cos u), z = w

where a is a positive constant.

(a) Find the basis unit vectors eu, ev and ew for this coordinate system

Answer is:eu =(− sin u sinh v, cos u cosh v − 1, 0)/cosh v − cos u
,ev =(1 − cos u cosh v, − sin u sinh v, 0)/cosh v − cos u
,ew = (0, 0, 1) But not sure how to get these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\underline{r} = \underline{r}(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ then If we change $u_1$ by a small amount, $du_1$, then $\underline{r}$ moves to position $(\underline{r} + d\underline{r})$, where

\begin{align}
d\underline{r} &= \frac{\partial \underline{r}}{\partial u_1}\,d u_1 \\
&= h_1 \,e_1 \,du_1
\end{align}
Where *scale factor* $h_1$ is given by
$$h_1 = \bigg|\frac{\partial \underline{r}}{\partial u_1}\bigg|$$

and the *base unit vector* $e_1$ is given by
$$e_1 = \frac{1}{h_1} \frac{\partial \underline{r}}{\partial u_1}$$

As an example (from Spherical Polar Coordinates), let $u_1 = r, u_2 = \theta, u_3 = \phi$ with

$$\underline{r} = r \sin \theta \cos \phi \textbf{i} + r\sin \theta \sin \phi \textbf{j}+r \cos \theta \textbf{k}$$

It's easy to show that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \underline{r}}{\partial r}&= \sin \theta \cos \phi \textbf{i} + \sin \theta \sin \phi \textbf{j}+\cos \theta \textbf{k} \implies h_r=1 \\
\frac{\partial \underline{r}}{\partial \theta}&= r \cos \theta \cos \phi \textbf{i} + r \cos  \theta \sin \phi \textbf{j}-r \sin \theta \textbf{k} \implies h_\theta=r \\
\frac{\partial \underline{r}}{\partial \phi}&= -r \sin \theta \sin \phi \textbf{i} + r \sin \theta \cos \phi \textbf{j}\implies h_\phi= r \sin \theta
\end{align}

Thus
\begin{align}
e_r &= \sin \theta \cos \phi \textbf{i} + \sin \theta \sin \phi \textbf{j}+\cos \theta \textbf{k} \\
e_\theta &= \cos \theta \cos \phi \textbf{i} + \cos \theta \sin \phi \textbf{j}-\sin \theta \textbf{k} \\
e_\phi &= -\sin \phi \textbf{i} + \cos \phi \textbf{j}
\end{align}

This method can then be applied to your example above.